# Canonical rotation to take a unit vector to another

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, canonical-transformation

In 3 (and 2 for that matter) dimensions, there is a "canonical" (independent of arbitrary choices) rotation that takes a given unit vector $u$ to another unit vector $v$ (**edit:** when $u,v$ are in general position): just rotate around the direction orthogonal to both vectors.

However, is there such a canonical rotation in higher dimensions?

Comment: true, let's say "vectors in general position"

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197772/generalized-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensional-space-around-n-2-unit-vector)