# Existence of Rotation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Given vectors $v_1, v_2 ... v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $||v_i||_2 = 1$ for all $i$ and $0 \leq\langle\ v_i,v_j\rangle \leq 1$ for all $i, j$. (Not all of them are 0 or 1). Does there always exist a rotation matrix which when applied to these vectors bring them to the positive orthant?
Clearly the fact is true for n = 2 and 3. Does it generalize to higher dimensions?

FYI, Not a HW Problem.

Comment: Define what you mean by a rotation matrix.

Comment: @amd, I mean successive applications of matrix of the kind as given in, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197772/generalized-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensional-space-around-n-2-unit-vector