# Calculate angle between two vectors, given their rotation w.r.t. a third vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry, rotations

I have three vectors, $\vec{a},\vec{b},$ and $\vec{c}$ in $n$-dimensional space. I know the coordinates of all three vectors and their dot products. Both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are rotated away from $\vec{c}$ by an angle $\alpha$, in their own respective directions, obtaining $\vec{a}'$ and $\vec{b}'$. What is the angle between $\vec{a}'$ and $\vec{b}'$?

I have worked on finding the generalized rotation matrices in $n$-dimensions, calculating $\vec{a}'$ and $\vec{b}'$ using Clifford Algebra using the answers from the posts below. However, these methods require many matrix operations and are too slow. I am wondering whether there is a neater solution without requiring the calculation of the two rotated $\vec{a}'$ and $\vec{b}'$ vectors first.

[Generalized rotation matrix in N dimensional space around N-2 unit vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197772/generalized-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensional-space-around-n-2-unit-vector)
[Finding the rotation matrix in n-dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598750/finding-the-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensions)
[How can I calculate a $4\times 4$ rotation matrix to match a 4d direction vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432057/how-can-i-calculate-a-4-times-4-rotation-matrix-to-match-a-4d-direction-vector/2161406#2161406)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "in their own respective dimensions"? Do you mean they're not in the span of $a,b,c$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Apologies for the confusion, $a$ simply moves away from $c$ by angle $\alpha$ and similar $b$ moves away from $c$ by angle $\alpha$, staying on the unit hypersphere. I meant to say, 'directions' I edited the question.

Comment: All the vectors, including $a'$ and $b'$ live in the 3D space spanned by $a,b, c$. The problem should be reducible to a problem in 3D. I suggest to use Gram-Schmidt process on $a, b, c$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a, b, c$ have norm 1, we have
\begin{align}
a' &= 2(a\cdot c)a - c\\
b' &= 2(b\cdot c)b - c\\
\end{align}
Indeed, this implies $a'\cdot a = a\cdot c$ and $a'\cdot c = 2(a\cdot c)^2-1$ which is the cosine of the double angle. Alternatively, it is obvious geometrically that $\frac{a'+c}{2}$ is the orthogonal projection of $c$ on $a$, that is to say $(a\cdot c) a$.

Hence
\begin{equation}
a'\cdot b' = 4 (a\cdot c)(b\cdot c)(a\cdot b) - 2(a\cdot c)^2 - 2(b\cdot c)^2
+1\end{equation}